# What does cause Antlr to create a large tokenstream resulting in out of memory

Tags: java, antlr3

One of our web applications regulary dies because its out of memory. The sparse data we gathered from memory dumps suggests there is an issue in our antlr parsing implementation. What we see is a antlr tokenstream containing more than a million items. The input text which causes this has yet to be found.

Is it possible this is somehow related to an zero width item beeing matched?
Could there be another issue in the grammer resulting in excessive memory usage?

Here is the current grammar we use:

```
grammar AdvancedQueries;

options {
  language = Java;
  output = AST;
  ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

tokens {
FOR;
END;
FIELDSEARCH;
TARGETFIELD;
RELATION;
NOTNODE;
ANDNODE;
NEARDISTANCE;
OUTOFPLACE;
}

@header {
package de.bsmo.fast.parsing;
}

@lexer::header {
package de.bsmo.fast.parsing;
}

startExpression  : orEx;

expressionLevel4    
: LPARENTHESIS! orEx RPARENTHESIS! | atomicExpression | outofplace;

expressionLevel3    
: (fieldExpression) | expressionLevel4 ;

expressionLevel2    
: (nearExpression) | expressionLevel3 ;

expressionLevel1    
: (countExpression) | expressionLevel2 ;


notEx   : NOT^? a=expressionLevel1 ;

andEx   : (notEx        -> notEx)
(AND? a=notEx -> ^(ANDNODE $andEx $a))*;

orEx    : andEx (OR^  andEx)*;

countExpression  : COUNT LPARENTHESIS countSub RPARENTHESIS RELATION NUMBERS -> ^(COUNT countSub RELATION NUMBERS);

countSub 
    :   orEx;

nearExpression  : NEAR LPARENTHESIS (WORD|PHRASE) MULTIPLESEPERATOR (WORD|PHRASE) MULTIPLESEPERATOR NUMBERS RPARENTHESIS -> ^(NEAR WORD* PHRASE* ^(NEARDISTANCE NUMBERS));

fieldExpression : WORD PROPERTYSEPERATOR fieldSub  -> ^(FIELDSEARCH ^(TARGETFIELD WORD) fieldSub );

fieldSub 
    :   WORD | PHRASE | LPARENTHESIS! orEx RPARENTHESIS!;  

atomicExpression 
: WORD
| PHRASE
| NUMBERS
;

//Out of place are elements captured that may be in the parseable input but need to be ommited from output later
//Those unwanted elements are captured here.
//MULTIPLESEPERATOR capture unwanted "," 
outofplace
: MULTIPLESEPERATOR -> ^(OUTOFPLACE ^(MULTIPLESEPERATOR));

fragment NUMBER : ('0'..'9');
fragment CHARACTER : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'*'|'?');
fragment QUOTE     : ('"');
fragment LESSTHEN : '<';
fragment MORETHEN: '>';
fragment EQUAL: '=';
fragment SPACE     : ('\u0009'|'\u0020'|'\u000C'|'\u00A0');

fragment WORDMATTER:  ('!'|'0'..'9'|'\u0023'..'\u0027'|'*'|'+'|'\u002D'..'\u0039'|'\u003F'..'\u007E'|'\u00A1'..'\uFFFE');

LPARENTHESIS : '(';
RPARENTHESIS : ')';

AND    : ('A'|'a')('N'|'n')('D'|'d');
OR     : ('O'|'o')('R'|'r');
ANDNOT : ('A'|'a')('N'|'n')('D'|'d')('N'|'n')('O'|'o')('T'|'t');
NOT    : ('N'|'n')('O'|'o')('T'|'t');
COUNT:('C'|'c')('O'|'o')('U'|'u')('N'|'n')('T'|'t');
NEAR:('N'|'n')('E'|'e')('A'|'a')('R'|'r');
PROPERTYSEPERATOR : ':';
MULTIPLESEPERATOR : ',';

WS     : (SPACE) { $channel=HIDDEN; };
NUMBERS : (NUMBER)+;
RELATION : (LESSTHEN | MORETHEN)? EQUAL // '<=', '>=', or '='
 | (LESSTHEN | MORETHEN);        // '<' or '>'
PHRASE : (QUOTE)(.)*(QUOTE);
WORD   : WORDMATTER* ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common cause of this is a token that can have length 0. There can be an infinite number of such a token between any two other tokens in the file. Defining a token like this now results in a compiler warning in ANTLR 4.

The following rule can match the empty string:

```
WORD : WORDMATTER*;
```

Perhaps you meant to use the following instead?

```
WORD : WORDMATTER+;
```

Comment: Sounds plausible, especially since this zero length matching is not been unheard off. Could you think of an input that triggers this? I mean antlr by default is greedy so how is it matching a zero length string?

Comment: It typically occurs when the input contains a sequence of characters that can't match any (non-zero length) token. A double-quoted string missing the final `"` should be enough to trigger it for your grammar.

Comment: Thanks! Hmm Antlrwork 1.4.3 or my Code does not choke on "xxxyyyzzz . My Original question is answered but its hard for me to understand why the error which presumably plagues our live servers can not be reproduced. Any ideas?

Comment: @ThomasS Try the input `$` (containing a single character that isn't allowed in any lexer rule). Or you could try the actual input you were feeding it on the server?